# How to stop Hadoop2 from retrying task attempts for certain class of exceptions

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

How can I stop Hadoop2 from retrying map/reduce tasks under certain failures. There is a class of failures which we can recover from and there is a class of failures from which we cannot recover. It makes sense to retry tasks for "recoverable" class of failures, and Hadoop2 already does that. But there are certain class of failures for which retrying does not make sense. And we should not spend any CPU cycles retrying this class of failures.

From the reading that I have done, looks like the tasks are retried for the following cases:

1. User code in the map or reduce task throws a runtime exception.
2. If streaming process exits with a nonzero exit code.
3. Sudden exit of child JVM
4. Tasktracker notices that it has not received progress update for a while and proceeds to mark the task as failed.

I read the first reason as "If the task throws any Exception inherited from java RuntimeException class, the task will be retried"

Am I correct in my understanding? I tried throwing an Error instead of a RuntimeException, but the tasks were retried nevertheless.

Im going to go through some hadoop source code and add any insights I find here. 
Any help is appreciated and will save a lot of my time.